# How to get rid of the name overlay on this vector control?

Tags: python, scripting, interface, properties

I can draw the control shown below on a panel using:

```
col = self.layout.column(align=True)
col.prop(bpy.context.scene.display, "light_direction")
```

But, the minute I try and add any sort of param, the whole control disappears. How can I remove the "Light Direction" label on the sphere?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Set the text argument.**

As with all properties in blender, can set the `text` argument to display something other than the property name, (the default)

[image]

```
def draw(self, context):
    scene = context.scene
    col = self.layout.column(align=True)
    col.prop(scene.display, "light_direction", text="")
```

Also note the usage of `context` as passed to the draw method, rather than using `bpy.context`

Comment: Thanks so much! Is context.scene different from bpy.context.scene ?

Comment: Thankyou. Re context: No. It is generally the case that the context passed is same. IMO simply good practice to use the argument provided, just  in case there are  changes in the future.  Outside scope of this question, the possibility for future as I see it is , can pass an overridden context to an operator. Would  be handy to know from within the operator what is "real" context and what is "fake".